# Multi line command when using runwait,%comspec% /c %mycmd% >%Log%

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that looks something like this:

```
tempLog = %temp%\tmp_ahklog.txt
Loc = C:\
mycmd = ver
runwait,%comspec% /c %mycmd% >%tempLog%, %Loc%

IfExist, %tempLog%
    run, Notepad.exe %tempLog%
```

How do I make it so that I can enter multiple lines of commands? For example, I want to run `ver` and `whoami`, and have the the return of both commands be in the text file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run your command twice and pipe both results into the same txt file? Your /c was right, so running this should not keep a CMD box open (verified). The first > creates a blank %templog% file and the >> in the second line appends onto the %templog% file. I executed DOS commands in the past, by using runwait without %comspec%, but those DOS commands were stored in a .bat file, so I actually ran: `runwait, abc.bat` which briefly opens a CMD box and closes it as soon as the .bat script has finished.

```
tempLog = C:\Temp\tmp_ahklog.txt
RunWait, %comspec% /c whoami > %tempLog% 
RunWait, %comspec% /c ver >> %tempLog %
IfExist, %tempLog%
    run, Notepad.exe %tempLog%
```

You could even combine both DOS commands in one line like this:

```
RunWait, %comspec% /c whoami > C:\Temp\Cmd.txt && ver >> C:\Temp\Cmd.txt
```

Comment: I guess I could. I guess I did not mention that I did not want all the cmd windows to be popping up. Whenever the `runwait` line is run, a new cmd window opens.

Comment: I am sorry, you mean I should do this `runwait,%comspec% %mycmd% >%tempLog%, %Loc%`